# android Load Image From gallary from a picasa album or from the Google+ Photos getting null

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-bitmap

I want to load image from gallary into code android.When i select an image from a picassa album or google+ photo, it retuns null.
I tried to get data by  uri.getPath(),  and it returns
  "/picasa/item/5667820546730991250 ";

How to get the image?

Answer (score 0):

The images in picasa album is **cloud**. you cant get the image uri from it. The *path could only be got from the images in the device*

Comment: This might Work ::
ContentResolver res = context.getContentResolver();
Uri uri = Uri.parse(intent.getData().toString());
res.openInputStream(uri);